# Determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{\sin x}{1+x} dx$.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm working on determining the convergence of this number series.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{\sin x}{1+x} dx$$

It seems that it converges to $0.552$ using Mathematica, but I have no idea how to prove its convergence. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\sin x <x$ and $\ln (1+x)=x+O(x^{2})$

Comment: Each term dominated by $\frac{1}{2n^2}$, hence it converges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\forall x\geq 0:~~ \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x}\leq x $$

Because, for all $x\geq 0$, $$\sin(x)\leq x,\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{1}{1+x}\leq 1$$

So $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\sin(x)}{1+x}dx\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}x \,dx = \frac{1}{2n^{2}}$$

And $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ is convergent.

Comment: Thank you so much!